# Is projectile angle for farthest distance same for human arm?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, biophysics

A projectile, in other words, travels the farthest when it is launched at an angle of 45 degrees. But human arm's velocity may vary at different angle, so angle for farthest distance may not be 45°.

Comment: You have a very valid point, but it could well be difficult to determine an answer - it's quite difficult to throw an object at a precise angle and measure the velocity

Comment: Another factor is drag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this might fully answer the question, but it certainly may help clarify some doubt.  The truth is, in cases such as Shot Put and Javelin, whereby the target location is lower than that of the human height, the optimal angle is not $45^o$ already.

Let's say we have a human height $h$, throwing a ball at initial velocity $u$ and at an angle $\theta$.

Considering $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ in the vertical, we have $-h=usin\theta t-\frac{g}{2}t^2$.

Using Quadratic identity, $t=\frac{usin\theta +\sqrt{u^2sin^2\theta+2gh}}{g}$

Considering the horizontal direction, we substitute the above expression of $t$ into $s=ucos\theta t$, getting $\frac{u^2sin\theta cos\theta+ucos\theta\sqrt{u^2sin^2\theta+2gh}}{g}=\frac{u^2}{2g}(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2gh}{u^2sin^2\theta}})sin2\theta$.

Of course, the biology of a person matters very much, so the "comfortable" angle can vary from person to person.  Not an expert in this, but I hope you get the rough idea.

Comment: The work makes sense. As $h\to\infty$ the optimum angle $\theta\to0$. The taller you are, the more horizontal you can throw, as you can take more advantage of the larger horizontal velocity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are defining the angle of the arm to be here, but I suppose it doesn't matter, at least for a first approximation. For a given initial velocity, and assuming no air resistance, you just need the projectile to leave your hand at a $45^\circ$ angle relative to the ground. The orientation of your arm wouldn't matter then.

Of course, how the projectile is thrown most likely determine the projectile's initial velocity. At that point you could argue your initial velocity is a function of the release angle, what you do with your hand, angle of your back, use of legs, etc, i.e. $v_0=v_0(\theta,\text{other factors})$. At that point I'm not sure how to determine this function. Perhaps someone has done some research on this. I'll have to look more into it, but it's probably fairly complicated. This will influence the range though, as the assumption "for a fixed initial velocity" described above no longer applies.

Comment: I would think otherwise.  Looking at this in a very practical scenario, a person has height, something that would affect the angle as well (since his target may not necessarily be something level.

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs You would think otherwise to what, specifically? The OP doesn't say anything about a target. Typically when talking about range we just assume a level surface. Talking about uneven surfaces is a unneeded complication.

Comment: hmm i get what you mean.  I was thinking more on the side of a shot put example, whereby the uneven surface cannot be neglected.  Thanks anyways, wanted to clarify.